# How to hide the BubbleWrap Media Player?

Tags: rubymotion

I'm using the rubygem bubble-wrap, having trouble finding how to make it hidden or invisible. Thank you so much.

```
BW::Media.play(local_file) do |media_player|
  media_player.view.frame = [[10, 100], [100, 100]]
  view << media_player.view
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're pushing the view as a subview onto your UIViewController's view, just do:

```
BW::Media.play(local_file) do |media_player|
  media_player.view.frame = [[10, 100], [100, 100]]
  view << media_player.view
  @media_player = media_player
end

# ...
@media_player.view.removeFromSuperview
```

Comment: It also works by adding `require 'bubble-wrap/ui'` in the rakefile, and then using `media_player.view.alpha = 0.0`. Thank you.